# Why Exception occurs in this simple python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I wrote this really simple Python program to learn how Exception works:

```
def Divide(x,y):
    try:
        print (int(a)/int(b))
    except:
        print "Exception Occured!"
```

But weirdly the exception occurs every time:

```
>>> Divide(int(1),int(2))
Exception Occured!
>>> Divide(1,2)
Exception Occured!
```

While it shouldn't occur:

```
>>> print 1/2
0
>>> print (1/2)
0
>>> print (int(1)/int(2))
0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you should try the same function without catching the exception blindly, but instead let it roll. You'll see the full error: `NameError: global name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: That's why I hate catching general exceptions.

Comment: First rule of exceptions is [don't use bare `except` clauses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` and `b` are not defined - argument names in the function signature are `x` and `y`

Answer (score 2):

```
def Divide(x,y):
    try:
        print (int(a)/int(b))
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Error: ' + str(e)
```

Try to write same code this way. You'll see why it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

because you should define a & b .

it's error is about global parameters :

```
          global name 'a' is not defined
```